# How to do jquery form validation in angular 2

Tags: jquery, angular

I am creating CRUD in angular 2.Here am trying to do field validation using jquery by adding `required` class.

```
 addFieldValue() { 
        $('.myForm').find('input.required').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() = '') {
                alert('empty')
            }
        })
        this.fieldArray.push(this.newAttribute)
        this.newAttribute = {};
    }
```

When I click add button without values,it should return `alert` box.
But function is not hitting inside `each` method. what I did wrong?

Full code:

`.HTML`

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered myForm">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let field of fieldArray; let i = index">
            <td>
                <span *ngIf="editDetails">{{field.code}}</span>
                <span *ngIf="updateDetails"><input [(ngModel)]="field.code" class="form-control required" type="text" name="{{field.code}}"/></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span *ngIf="editDetails">{{field.name}}</span>
                <span *ngIf="updateDetails"><input [(ngModel)]="field.name" class="form-control required" type="text" name="{{field.name}}"/></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span *ngIf="editDetails">{{field.price}}</span>
                <span *ngIf="updateDetails"><input [(ngModel)]="field.price" class="form-control required" type="text" name="{{field.price}}"/></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" (click)="editFieldValue(i,field)" *ngIf="editDetails">Edit</button>
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" (click)="updateFieldValue(i)" *ngIf="updateDetails">Update</button>
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" (click)="deleteFieldValue(i)">Delete</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="newAttributeCode" [(ngModel)]="newAttribute.code" name="newAttributeCode" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="newAttributeName" [(ngModel)]="newAttribute.name" name="newAttributeName" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="newAttributePrice" [(ngModel)]="newAttribute.price" name="newAttributePrice" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" (click)="addFieldValue()">Add</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

`.TS`

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
declare var $: any;
@Component({

    selector: 'my-employee',
    templateUrl : `app/employee/employee.component.html`
})
export class EmployeeComponent {    
    updateDetails: boolean = false;
    editDetails: boolean = true;
    private fieldArray: Array<any> = [];
    private newAttribute: any = {};

    addFieldValue() { 
        $('.myForm').find('input.required').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() = '') {
                alert('empty')
            }
        })
        this.fieldArray.push(this.newAttribute)
        this.newAttribute = {};
    }
    editFieldValue(i, field) {
        console.log(i)
        this.updateDetails = true;
        this.editDetails= false;
    }
    updateFieldValue() {
        this.updateDetails= false;
        this.editDetails = true;
    }
    deleteFieldValue(index) {
        this.fieldArray.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are using `=` for compare which is wrong, because it's assigning and not comparing . Use `==` to compare values

If alert isn't firing in each loop, then I think you could try something like this:

```
addFieldValue() {
    var errors = [];
    $('.myForm').find('input.required').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            errors.push($(this));
        }
    });

    if(errors.length > 0) {
        alert("Please fill all input fields");
    }

    this.fieldArray.push(this.newAttribute)
    this.newAttribute = {};
}
```

Here is working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sh228g3b/1/) I made for you, but in jQuery style

Comment: errors is an empty array and we defined it at the beginning of the function. As you said that alert isn't firing inside each loop(whitch might be wrong, because you had error with comparing, I thought that if validation error is found we can simply add something to errors array and then check if it's not empty, then that would mean there are errors and we alert about it